# How to Fix "the type initializer for 'FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp' threw an exception"

Tags: c#, firebase, wcf

I have a wcf service that I am trying to connect to Firebase purely for push messaging services. I need to send xml from a classic asp server (I know it's old, but I have no control over it) to my wcf web service, which will handle all of the firebase messaging.

I installed the firebase admin sdk in the wcf service and have successfully used it to send a notification to a specified device when running the wcf service in iis on my localhost, however when I publish to the prod server I am getting the above exception at the `FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp.Create()` method call.

Here is my code in the wcf service:

```
public List<string> OnSafetyMessagePosted(List<user> users)
        {
            List<string> strings = new List<string>();

            if (users != null && users.Count > 0)
            {
                // Authenticate with Firebase using Google json auth file
                try
                {
                    if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
                    {
                        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
                        {
                            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile($@" 
                                  {AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}" +
                                  "\\project-####-firebase-adminsdk-####-######.json""),
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    throw new FaultException($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}" +
                    "\\project-####-firebase-adminsdk-####-######.json" + $"\n{ex.Message}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new FaultException(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                }



                // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
                var registrationToken = "cXM76XuqHlY:.....";

                // See documentation on defining a message payload.
                var notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = "Hello From Firebase!",
                    Body = "Sample Notification"
                };


                var message = new Message()
                {
                    Notification = notification,
                    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "userID", users[0].userID.ToString() }
                    },
                    Token = registrationToken,
                };

                // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
                // registration token.
                string response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).Result;

                strings.Add(message.ToString());
            }

            return strings;
        }
```

The result I am getting from postman is a 400 error with the following stacktrace:

```
The type initializer for
            'FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp' threw an exception. at FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp.Create(AppOptions options,
            String name)
            at FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp.Create(AppOptions options)
            at SeqCompanionSrv.SeqCompSrv.OnSafetyMessagePosted(List`1 users) in C:\source\repos\Sequence Companion
            Service\SeqCompanionSrv\SeqCompSrv.svc.cs:line 387'
```

My suspicion is that since I already created a FirebaseApp instance on my localhost, that the same key won't work for the server. I tried generating a new key pair for my service account and used that, but I get the same results: it works on localhost, but not remote server.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In my experience you should be able to use the same key but it's good practice to create different keys for use instances

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just had the same problem, came looking for answers myself and found nothing.

To fix, I had Dependents missing from my Web.config!

```
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Or in my case, it was wrong version in Web.config as I had just updated Firebase SDK which came with updates to various Google.Apis.* libraries

Answer (score 0):

This may not be suitable for this question, but I came here with the same exception thrown.

I found that when I updated the server, I was missing the file...

System.Collections.Immutable.dll

It is one of the dependencies of FirebaseAdmin